# How to retrieve original dataframe after a filtered spread dplyr command

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My original dataframe, `df2` :

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100464", "1100464"),
                  CATEGORIE = c("10110", "10160", "10604", "11220", "10110", "10110","10140"),
                  RANK =  c("1", "1", "1", "1", "0" ,"1", "1"),
                  MD =  c("0", "0", "0", "3", "4", "0", "0" ),
                  PROD3 = c(2345.00,1114.58,501.40,0.00,0.00,2720.00,636.80),
                  VALUE3 = c(540.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  AREA3 = c(563.76,0.00,17.35,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  LONG3 = c(4100,2100,1740,265,0,3978,940)
)
```

I run this command to spread some news columns with value according to PROD3, and name according to MD, it works great but I lose all the others row :

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
         filter(CATEGORIE == "10110") %>%
         mutate(name = str_c("aaaa", MD, "aaa", sep = "_"),
                value = PROD3) %>%
         spread(name, value)
df3
```

How can I keep all the rows of the `df2` in `df3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you lose all the rows due to the `filter` which you apply to make your spread conditional.

There are two ways around this:

**1) Do not filter!**

Instead of using filter, try to use a more conditional approach like this:

```r
df3 <- df2 %>%
         mutate(name = case_when(
                                CATEGORIE == "10110" ~ str_c("aaaa", MD, "aaa", sep = "_"),
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_),
                value = PROD3) %>%
         spread(name, value)
```

**2) Save intermediary results**

You could also use your original df3 to amend df2 via a join

```r
df3 <- df2 %>%
      left_join(df3, by = "ID")
```

Comment: It looks very good, however, the first solution create a NA columns with all PROD3 value, but i can just remove it afterward, the second solution could be nice also but I dont have unique ID on the table so I need to figure out a key...

Comment: @krifur They key can also be a combination of two variables if that is unique. e.g. like this: ```left_join(df3, by = c("ID","CATEGORIE"))```.